# Restrict usage of annotations in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, scala-macros

Given a custom defined annotation `class GreaterThan(m: Double) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation` and a case class `case class Person(name: String, @GreaterThan(0) age: Double)`, how can make sure that the uses of the annotation `GreaterThan`are used on doubles but not strings, obviously `GreaterThan` does not make sense to use on the `name` parameter.

Is there a way to emit a warning if the user uses an annotation in the wrong place( that I define), or like an error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Macro annotations transform untyped trees, so you should use `c.typecheck`

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

class GreaterThan(m: Double) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro GreaterThanMacro.impl
}
object GreaterThanMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    annottees match {
      case q"$_ val $_: $tpt = $_" :: tail =>
        if (!(c.typecheck(tq"$tpt", mode = c.TYPEmode).tpe <:< typeOf[Double]))
          c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$tpt is not Double")
 
        q"..$tail"
    }
  }
}
```

```
case class Person(name: String, @GreaterThan(0) age: Double) // compiles

  // doesn't compile: String is not Double
// case class Person(@GreaterThan(0) name: String, age: Double)
```

Besides `c.abort` there are `c.error`, `c.warning`.

Please beware of limitations for type checking in macro annotations (when a type is defined in the same scope where annotation is expanded)

```
type Dbl = Double // outer scope

{
  case class Person(name: String, @GreaterThan(0) age: Dbl) // compiles
}
```

```
type Dbl = Double // the same scope

  // doesn't compile: scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: not found: type Dbl
// case class Person(name: String, @GreaterThan(0) age: Dbl)
```

[Scala whitebox macro how to check if class fields are of type of a case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886070/scala-whitebox-macro-how-to-check-if-class-fields-are-of-type-of-a-case-class)

Sometimes implicit macros (macro-generated type classes) can be an alternative to macro annotations.

Maybe you could also try the library https://github.com/fthomas/refined/

```
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric.Positive

case class Person(name: String, age: Double Refined Positive)
```

Comment: Can I access the Refined types information (`Refined Positive`) using reflection?

Comment: @outlaw I hope by reflection you mean compile-time reflection (macros). In such case yes I guess you do (although this can depend on what you mean by information). `Double Refined Positive` is `Refined[Double, Positive]` so just the type of a field. If you mean runtime reflection then because of type erasure `Refined[Double, Positive]` is just `Refined[_, _]` so you'll need `TypeTag`s to restore type arguments.